# Java 7 NIO2 Files.walk NotDirectoryException

Tags: java, nio

I have a SymbolicLink pointing to his parent Directory yep is weird but i was trying to understand FileSystemLoopException i already did it. But another problem come out.

I have the following code.

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
public final class FileLoopSystemException{
    private final Path target = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Documents\\SymbolicLinks\\Folder\\SubDirectorio\\SymbolicApuntandoADirectorioLink.txt");
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
         final FileLoopSystemException clazz = new FileLoopSystemException();
         clazz.walk();
    }
    private void walk()throws Exception{
         System.out.println("Exist: "+Files.exists(target));//false
         System.out.println("Directory: "+Files.isDirectory(target));//true
         System.out.println("Symbolic: "+Files.isSymbolicLink(target));//true
         System.out.println("RegularFile: "+Files.isRegularFile(target));//false
         final long count = Files.walk(target,java.nio.file.FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS)
            .peek(a->System.out.println(Files.isSymbolicLink(a)+" "+a))
            .count();
         System.out.println("count = " + count);
    }        
}
```

But throws

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NotDirectoryException: C:\Users\Documents\SymbolicLinks\Folder\SubDirectorio\SymbolicApuntandoADirectorioLink.txt
```

I am using the FollowLink Option but i dont know even when the target is follow which is a directory why Files.walk says is not a directory if i not pass the FOLLOW_LINK option is printed the file itself which is OK because is not follow.

In resume why Files.walk cant transverse my target which is a directory and is follow??

The API says

```
Checked exception thrown when a file system operation, intended for a directory, fails because the file is not a directory.
```

But it is a directory and is follow just because is was treat it as a regular file it would print the file name instead the link is follow and the directory is set but Java doesn't recognize as a REGULAR directory?

My FileSystem is something like.

```
C:\Users\Documents\SymbolicLinks\Folder\SubDirectorio
   ....SymbolicApuntandoADirectorioLink.txt -->SymbolicLink pointing to parent directory SubDirectorio
```

Comment: Just a note, `Files.walk` is available since Java 8.

Comment: Could you please post what the target of `SymbolicApuntandoADirectorioLink.txt` is. E.g. `dir SymbolicApuntandoADirectorioLink.*`

Comment: is done @SubOptimal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably `SymbolicApuntandoADirectorioLink.txt` is a `file symbolic link` to the parent directory, instead of a `directory symbolic link`.

```
cd c:\temp
mkdir dir1
cd dir1
mklink file.link ..
mklink /d dir.link ..
dir
...
11/06/2018  15:03    <SYMLINKD>     dir.link [..]
11/06/2018  15:02    <SYMLINK>      file.link [..]
```

Running your code for `file.lnk` fails with

```
Exist: false
Directory: true
Symbolic: true
RegularFile: false
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NotDirectoryException: C:\temp\dir1\file.link
```

Running your code for `dir.link` fails with

```
Exist: true
Directory: true
Symbolic: true
RegularFile: false
true C:\temp\dir1\dir.link
Exception in thread "main" java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.file.FileSystemLoopException: C:\temp\dir1\dir.link\dir1\dir.link
```

Comment: It works like a charm you are correct. I wasn't knew what a symbolic link exist 15 days ago. And i didn't knew a /d even exist is working know. Thanks a lot.